# What is the Hound singing?

Tags: game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes, music

I came across this behind-the-scenes video from *Game of Thrones*. What is the song Rory McCann singing? Is it a modern "pop" song or some folk song?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yellow Bird - The Mills Brothers

The part Rory McCann is singing starts roughly 30 seconds in.

Comment: Awesome find! It make we wonder if the song was ever redone as Rory seems to be much more upbeat/tempo or if it is just his accent/enthusiasm.

Comment: Oh man, it's Kristofer Hivju that makes it extra awesome for sure!